# xubuntu lightdm unity-greeter bad looking theme

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, unity-greeter

I'm using xubuntu 12.10 and wanted to use the `unity-greeter` for the login screen (lightdm). The thing is that I installed the package `unity-greeter` (and gnome-settings-daemon), changed to `unity-greeter` in the `lightdm.conf` file but the login screen turned out something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7pDM.png and this [http://i.imgur.com/QTdu0Xo.png](https://i.imgur.com/QTdu0Xo.png) (please ignore the vertical panel, I used the `--test-mode` to take the screenshots). As you can see the theme doesn't look as it should, there are those "old" icons used and when I click to select the environment it can be seen that the windows look like beeing an old debian theme.

What can I do to make it look "normal" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, you are missing some packages.

This  should be `ubuntu-artwork` and if that fails, `ubuntu-desktop` will throw in the remainder.

However, if you are disappointed by the xubuntu greeter, having a look at the [elementary project](http://elementaryos.org/) might help.

Comment: For me, only installing `light-themes` (dependency of `ubuntu-artwork`) worked fine.